# Haskell type error occurs when compiling two code snippets together that separately raise no error

Tags: haskell

I am having a type issue with Haskell, the program below throws the compile time error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘bytestring-0.10.8.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’ with actual type ‘Text’
```

Program is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

...

import Control.Concurrent (MVar, newMVar, modifyMVar_, modifyMVar, readMVar)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import qualified Network.WebSockets as WS
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Aeson (decode)

...

application :: MVar ServerState -> WS.ServerApp
application state pending = do
    conn <- WS.acceptRequest pending
    msg <- WS.receiveData conn
    -- EITHER this line can be included
    T.putStrLn msg
    -- OR these two lines, but not both
    decodedObject <- return (decode msg :: Maybe (Map String Int))
    print decodedObject

...
```

It seems to me that the basic issue is that [putStrLn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text-IO.html) expects `Text` whereas [decode](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html) expects `Bytetring`.

What I don't get is why I can run this section of the code:

```
T.putStrLn msg
```

Or I can run this section of the code:

```
decodedObject <- return (decode msg :: Maybe (Map String Int))
print decodedObject
```

But not both together.

What is the proper way to resolve this issue in the program?

I guess this is something like Type Coercion, or Type Inference, or what would be Casting in other languages. The problem is I don't know how to phrase the problem clearly enough to look it up.

It's as if `msg` can be one of a number of Types, but as soon as it is forced to be one Type, it can't then be another...

I'm also not sure if this overlaps with Overloaded strings. I have the pragma and am compiling with `-XOverloadedStrings`

I'm quite a newbie, so hope this is a reasonable question.

Any advice gratefully received! Thanks

Comment: Nothing is casted here, the type of `WS.receiveData conn` is polymorphic in its return type. The equivalent in Java would be a generic method and in C++ it'd be a template. The difference is that neither Java nor C++ can infer type arguments that are only used as the return type, so in Java or C++ you'd have to explicitly write `receiveData<Text>(conn)` to get a `Text` or `receiveData<ByteString>(conn)` to get a `ByteString`. Haskell is smart enough to infer this based on what you do with the result, but if you use it as both a `ByteString` *and* a `Text`, that no longer works.

Comment: A `ByteString` is a sequence of bytes, while a `Text` is a sequence of characters. You can turn a `ByteString` into a `Text` only if you know that the bytes are indeed text, and which _encoding_ is being used. For instance, you can use `decodeUtf8 :: ByteString -> Text` from `Data.Text.Encoding`

Comment: Thanks @sepp2k, @ chi, thats really helpful, think I understand it all now, and summed it up in my extra answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `WS.receiveData` is polymorphic on its return type:

```
receiveData :: WebSocketsData a => Connection -> IO a
```

it only needs to be `WebSocketsData a` instance, which both `Text` and `ByteString` are. So the compiler just infers the type.

I suggest you just assume it's a `ByteString`, and convert in `Text` upon the `putStrLn` usage.

Comment: Thanks Kostiantyn, really helpful. Just for posterity I summed up my understanding of that below. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their advice. My final understanding is that any value in Haskell can be polymorphic until you force it to settle on a type, at which point it can't be any other type (stupid, but I hadn't seen a clear example of that before).

In my example, [WS.receiveData](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-0.12.5.2/docs/Network-WebSockets.html) returns polymorphic `IO a` where `a` is an instance of class [WebsocketData](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/websockets-0.12.5.2/docs/Network-WebSockets.html#t:WebSocketsData) which itself is parameterised by a type which can be either `Text` or `Bytestring`.

[Aeson decode](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:decode) expects a (lazy) `Bytestring`. Assuming that we settle on (lazy) `Bytestring` for our `a`, this means the first line that I mentioned before needs to become:

```
T.putStrLn $ toStrict $ decodeUtf8 msg
```

to convert the lazy `ByteString` to a strict `Text`. I can do this so long as I know the incoming websocket message is UTF8 encoded.

I may have got some wording wrong there, but think that's basically it.

Comment: That's not quite it. Values *can* be polymorphic, but only if they're let-bound (and the monomorphism restriction is disabled or you provide an explicit type signature). In that case, you will actually be able to use the same value as different types and it will never settle on a type. In your case `msg` does not have a polymorphic type because it's bound by `<-`, which desugars to `>>=` with a lambda. So `msg` needs a monomorphic type, which the compiler infers by looking at how `msg` is used in the rest of its scope. In cases where the compiler can't infer this, ...

Comment: ... you'll have to provide an explicit type signature.